# Swift Diffable Snapshot - Add new Section to Snapshot and Reload Collection View

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, snapshot, diffabledatasource, uicollectionviewdiffabledatasource

I have a collection view that has sections and the beginning. I want to add a new section after the user creates data and display data in the new section. Here is the code I have tried but failed. The new section does not appear after running the code.

```
var snapshot = self.collectionView.diffableDataSource.snapshot()

let recentlySection = Section(title: "Recently Colored",
                                      cells: [userPicture],
                                      sectionType: .recentlyColored)
        
snapshot.appendSections([recentlySection])
snapshot.appendItems([userPicture], toSection: recentlySection)

self.collectionView.diffableDataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: true)
self.collectionView.reloadData()
```

Thank you!

Comment: you shouldn't be calling `reloadData` when using the diffable framework. Whole point is you leave it up to the system to cater for those changes. Without knowing a little more about your setup, the apply should be sufficient when decoupled from the collectionview.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I totally agree with you. It was the my first time of using diffable framework. I fixed it. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my problem. I am leaving answer here in case of anyone encounters the same problem. I forgot to add new section to my collection view sections list.
Adding this line solved my problem.

```
self.collectionView.sections.insert(recentlySection, at: 2)
```